# Elasticsearch multindex performance

Tags: lucene, indexing, elasticsearch

I'm thinking about moving from one index to day-based indexes ([`multi-index`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/multi-index.html)) in our `Elasticsearch` cluster with huge number of records.

The actual question is how it can affect the performance of indexing, searching and mapping in the ES cluster?

Is it take more time to search through one huge index than from a hundreds of big indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will take less time to search through one large index, rather than hundreds of smaller ones.

Breaking an index in this fashion could help performance if you will be primarily searching only one of the broken out indexes.  In your case, if you most often will need to search for records added on a particular day, then you might be helped by this, performance-wise.  If you will mostly be searching across the entire of range of indexes, you would generally be better off searching in the single monolithic index.

Comment: sure, i'm feeling it like you said. The main point of decomposition is to provide a search for particular day (or a few days). But what if sometime i need to search through all of them? 

Do you know some links or data how speed changes (with numbers, if possible)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I was quite curious myself to see some numbers on how much of an impact this sort of implementation would have.  Didn't have luck actually finding it.  And, of course, how relevant it would really be to your case would probably depend on a number of variables (size of indexes, type of data stored, data indexed, duplication of terms across indexes, query complexity, multi-thread/processing, just to guess at a few such variables).

Comment: Sure, relevance of experiments is always a question, but at least it can help estimate how significant changes can imply on performance. By the way, just got an opinion, that multi-index can increase performance if you have on node per index (of course, not relevant in my case) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we have implemented `ES` multi-indexing in our company. For our application we chose monthly indices strategy, so we create a new index every month.

Of course, as it was advised by @femtoRgon, the search through all smaller indices takes a little bit more, but speed of application has been increased because of its logic.

So, my advice to everybody who wants to move from one index to multi-indices: **make research of your application needs** and select appropriate slices of the whole index (if it's really needed).

*As example*, i can share some results of research of our application, that helped us to make a decision to use monthly indices:

- 90-95% of our queries are only for last 3 months
- we have about 4 big groups of queries: today, last week, last month and last 3 months (of course, we could create weekly or daily indices, but they would be too small, since we don't have enough documents inside)
- we can explain to customers why he need to wait if he makes "non usual" query across whole period (all indices).